# Is it possible to execute upsert in a custom constraint when using diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using this rust code to do an upsert right now:

```
diesel::insert_into(favorites::table)
        .values(&new_fav)
        .on_conflict(id)
        .do_update()
        .set(like_status.eq(1))
        .execute(&connection)
        .unwrap();
```

but the execute log shows error:

```
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: DatabaseError(UniqueViolation, "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"fav_uniq_idx\"")', src/service/music/music_service.rs:49:10
```

`fav_uniq_idx` is a custom uniq constraint in PostgreSQL 13, define it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE public.favorites ADD CONSTRAINT unique_idx UNIQUE (source_id, user_id);
```

is it possible to define the conflict handle logic in rust diesel code about custom constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
diesel::insert_into(favorites::table)
        .values(&new_fav)
        .on_conflict(on_constraint("unique_idx"))
        .do_update()
        .set(like_status.eq(1))
        .execute(&connection)
        .unwrap();
```

works.